# Looking for tutorial about automation real iOS devices with Appium

Tags: ios, automation, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, appium

There is some useful tutorial which you could advice? I learned how write and run test with Emulator but can't understand how to run on real iOS devices (what I provide in the code, how properly Appium server should be run, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have mentioned both the ways [here](http://smritituteja.in/ios-mobile-automation-using-appium/) along with basic scripting.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've been trying to launch the real ihpone device by using appium app , I've configured UDID & BundleID param , but I'm getting the next error : Could not determine your device from Appium arguments or desired capabilities. Please make sure to specify the 'deviceName' and 'platformName' capabilities
any idea ? I'm not launching it trough the command line or some code but using the appium app. where exactly can I define an additional parameters ? Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what all did you select in all the Appium parameters for launch?